# Empty interface{} in function type

Tags: function, interface, go

An object of any type can be assigned to an empty interface. For example, we have the following function

```
func Println(i interface{} ) {
  fmt.Println(i)
}
```

We can call it by

```
Println(3)
Println(1.5)
Println("Hello")
```

But I can't achieve the same thing for function type

```
func Map(fn func( interface{} )) {  
  ......  
}
```

I cannot call this with
`Map( func( i int) {......} )`
because the type `func(int)` is different from the type `func( interface{} )`.

But when I define `func( interface{} )`, I really mean any type of the input parameters. How can I achieve this in Go?

Comment: They are different "types". A function accepting an interface and a function accepting an int are different things.

Comment: Yes, I know the types are different. But is it possible for me to define a function type to accept any type parameters?

Answer (score 13):

It fails because the signatures don't match.

When you call `Println(3)`, the function isn't taking an integer as its first argument.  Rather the integer gets packed inside an `interface{}` variable (an automatic conversion, since integers conform to the interface), and that variable is passed to the function.  This conversion happens on the calling side, so the process of calling the function is different to calling a function matching `func(i int)`.

If you want to write a function that accepts arbitrary unary functions, you will need to declare it to take an `interface{}` variable as its argument and then check the value using the `reflect` package.  The `reflect` package can also help you call arbitrary functions where you don't know the signature at compile time.

For example:

```
func Map(f, v interface{}) interface{} {
    fn := reflect.ValueOf(f)
    fnType := fn.Type()
    if fnType.Kind() != reflect.Func || fnType.NumIn() != 1 || fnType.NumOut() != 1 {
        panic("Expected a unary function returning a single value")
    }
    res := fn.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(v)})
    return res[0].Interface()
}
```

This will call the given function `f` with the argument `v` and return the result.  Provided `v` is assignable to `f`'s first argument the call will succeed without a panic.  You can experiment with this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/kkBu56JYb8

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I actually know how to use interface{} and reflect package to achieve this. But asking the caller to supply a non-intuitive function with interface{} is not nice enough. How can we achieve the automatic conversion from int to interface{}?

Comment: This is exactly why the lack of generics cripple the functional aspects of the language.

Comment: @YiqunHu What do you mean by "asking the caller to supply a non-intuitive function with interface{}"? The example at http://play.golang.org/p/kkBu56JYb8 calls `Map` in the exact same way as you described in the question. Are you saying that the callers won't understand what needs to be passed if they see an `interface{}` instead of `func (interface{})` as a parameter to `Map`?

Answer (score 1):

I do realise its an old discussion, but came across the post and wanted to play around with the concept of having arbitrary function `func (interface{})` within another function, instead of `interface{}`.
I could write a simple implementation, by providing an inline implementation of a function which would accept `interface{}`. And we can call this function from within another function

```
varForGenFunc := func(in interface{}) int {                             
                    fmt.Println("type of this object: ",reflect.TypeOf(in))
                    return 1}

TakeGenericFunc(varForGenFunc, variableForGen)
```

Going by this, we can write any implementations of `func(interface{})` and pass it as parameter to `TakeGenericFunc`

You can play around with it here:

https://play.golang.org/p/f5UUhyhEx7u

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the example. I did not t like the return type int of the generic function, made that also as an interface, https://play.golang.org/p/kPlgCEzPSUs